# Generate a variable length hash

Tags: python, hash

Is there a way in python to generate a short version of hashcode, SHA128 or SHA256
I tried this but its not correct way to get[extracting substring to shorten]

```
hashlib.sha256(str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:8]
```

for example if i have a string, i want 8 character hash

```
str = "iamtestingastringtogethash"
print(hashlib.sha256(str.encode('utf-8').hexdigest(),8))
```

> Output: some_8char_hash

Comment: What's wrong with `hashlib.sha256(str.encode('utf-8')).hexdigest()[:8]`?

Comment: Hash lengths cannot be arbitrary as that would increase the chance of collisions. Imagine specifying a hash length of 1 as a boundary case.

Comment: in this case i am trimming a generated hash to 8 chr instead of generating a 8 character hash, thats my problem

Comment: I don't really see a difference. The hash function is doing that internally to get to ... whatever length sha is.

Answer (score 6):

Ok i found my own fix,

```
hashlib.shake_256(str.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(length=8)
```

Comment: error: hexdigest() take no keyword arguments

Answer (score 0):

As per the hashlib source code hexdigest method looks for integer value as input without a keyword

```
def hexdigest(self, __length: int) -> str: ...
```

the following will do the work without the keyword length and double of input number is the total length

```
hashlib.shake_256(str.encode("utf-8")).hexdigest(4)
```